# How do I remove the first letter of every string in array with splice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, splice

I have an array that contains multiple strings.  I need to store each string minus the first letter and then concatenate them into a sentence.

I am trying:

```
var missingFirstLetter = array[i].splice(1);
```

What I have found online guides me to believe this should work, but it doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *slice (not splice!) each element of the array and then store it back into an array*, which you can do with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which maps each element to a new value, in this case the string without the first letter:

```
var arrayNoFirstLetter = array.map(el => el.slice(1));
```

This will iterate through the array and map each element to a new string without the first letter and store the new array of strings into `arrayNoFirstLetter`. Make sure to use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to get a section of a string, because there is not `String#splice` method. (maybe you mistook it for `Array#splice`?) Then you can use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join them with a delimiter (which is the string between each element when joined together):

```
var joined = arrayNoFirstLetter.join(""); //join with empty space for example
```

For example:

```
var array = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Pears"];
var arrayNoFirstLetter = array.map(el => el.slice(1)); // ["pples", "ranges", "ears"]
var joined = arrayNoFirstLetter.join(""); // "pplesrangesears"
```

Comment: Yes Andrew,
"Make sure to use String#slice to get a section of a string, because there is not String#splice method. (maybe you mistook it for Array#splice?)"
Is exactly what I was doing.

I ended up using .substring(1) on each to take the rest of the word.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you wanted?

```
var strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
    stringsNoFirstCh = [];

for(key in strings){ // Iterates through each string in an array
   let string = strings[key];
   var s = string.substring(1); // Gets a string starting from index 1, so omits the first char
   stringsNoFirstCh.push(s); // Add to a new array: ['tring1', 'tring2', 'tring3']
}

var string = stringsNoFirstCh.join(''); // Transform to a string: tring1tring2tring3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a=["hHello","+-I-am","d-evil"];
var x;
var z="";
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
x=a[i].substring(1);
z=z+x;
}
console.log(z);
```

Result is :

```
Hello-I-am-evil
```